# Not able to import class in import section , class name is not being visible

Tags: java, selenium, class

so here is my simple scenario , i want to import a class shown in the picture [image: import canel_popup.java into Task_testng.jave]

when I write import and start writing class name it should popup with an exact class name and then it writes pages.pom.class, but that is not happening don't know what is the reason i am stuck on it for a while , i want to use a function written in canel_popup.java for that i want to import pom_class package

[image]

here you can see that i am not able to import pom_class

Comment: Is the class/package you are trying to use on the path?

Comment: no i am not using path simply i am writing import pom_class in task_testng import section

Comment: I meant: is it on the classpath?

Comment: I am extremely sorry i am not getting your point

Comment: if a package is not on the classpath, it won't be found, and you can't use it. Make sure all the packages/classes you are trying to use are on the classpath

Comment: how to set package onto classpath , can you help with this

Comment: Does  `Canel_popup.java` contains a package declaration `package pom_class;` at the top? And try to write a whole import `import pom_class.Canel_popup;` to check if the error will also be present.